# Extract values from a file and average

Tags: r, bash, shell, gnuplot

I have a file which from which I'd like to extract two values (Time, C_F[6]) highlighted below. Its in a CentOS 7 environment so can use bash or gnuplot or r. I'm not even sure how to google that (e.g. extract values from file bash doesn't really come up with solutions). Is it possile?

I'd like to be able to:

1. plot Time vs C_F[6]
2. Average C_F[6]

[image]

EDIT 1:

I think this might be on the lines, but it reproduces the whole file
sed 's/^.*C_F[6]=//' C_F.pressure > outputfile

EDIT 2:

```
Extract of the file:

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  3.0.0                                 |
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      www.OpenFOAM.org                      |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Build  : 3.0.0-6abec57f5449
Exec   : patchAverage p C_F -parallel
Date   : Apr 15 2017
Time   : 15:01:20
Host   : "login2.jjj.uk"
PID    : 59764
Case   : /nobackup/jjjj/Silsoe/Solid/solid_0_LES/motorBikeLES
nProcs : 8
Slaves :
7
(
"login2.jjjj.59765"
"login2.jjjj.59766"
"login2.jjjj.59767"
"login2.jjjj.59768"
"login2.jjjj.59769"
"login2.jjjj.59770"
"login2.jjjj.59771"
)

Pstream initialized with:
    floatTransfer      : 0
    nProcsSimpleSum    : 0
    commsType          : nonBlocking
    polling iterations : 0
sigFpe : Enabling floating point exception trapping (FOAM_SIGFPE).
fileModificationChecking : Monitoring run-time modified files using timeStampMaster
allowSystemOperations : Allowing user-supplied system call operations

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
Create time

Create mesh for time = 0.18

Time = 0.18
    Reading volScalarField p
    Average of volScalarField over patch C_F[6] = -18.3176

Time = 0.19
    Reading volScalarField p
    Average of volScalarField over patch C_F[6] = -18.299

Time = 0.2
    Reading volScalarField p
    Average of volScalarField over patch C_F[6] = -18.2704

Time = 0.21
    Reading volScalarField p
    Average of volScalarField over patch C_F[6] = -18.2349
```

Comment: can you link a sample file? What I do in these cases is to extract the lines (using functions like `readLine`) of the file, then find the lines (using `grep` or similar functions) containing certain pattern like `Time = ` and `C_F[6]`. And maybe clean those lines so that the numeric portion will be left. You can copy paste the text from `//**************** ` up to where ever for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crude way to do things:

```
# extract text from file line by line; will be indexed by line
sample <- readLines("D:\\tempFiles/example.txt")

# index the lines contaning "Time = "
timeI <- grep(x = sample, pattern = "Time = ")

# index the lines contaning "C_F[6]"; note that \\ is escape for [ and ]
C_FI <- grep(x = sample, pattern = "C_F\\[6\\]")

# extract lines and clean them
# note that these lines only contain "Time = values"; so just remove the "Time = "
timeval <-as.numeric(gsub(x = sample[timeI], pattern = "Time = ", replacement = ""))

# extract lines and clean them
# note that gsub removes all characters from te start (^) until "= "
C_FIval <- as.numeric(gsub(x = sample[C_FI], pattern = "^.*= ", ""))


# plot timve vs CF[6]
plot(y = timeval, x = C_FIval )

# get the mean
mean(C_FIval)
```

There are more elegant ways for the regex, but I'm still finding my way through that. This should be a basic way.

Comment: Thank you. This works nicely. Can this be run from the command line in unix?

Comment: I believe yes. Try including the path for Rscript.exe binary, just like how you add the path for the bash. Haven't tried this one though.

Comment: tested it and worked fine, though explicitly calling `Rscript.ext nameofscript.R`; also, you might want to play around with how you want to extract the outputs like plots (maybe create a device for the plot) and a text output for the mean etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it does exactly what I was hoping for. I like the fact that running Rscript pressure.R automatically makes a pdf file with a plot.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP tagged also gnuplot, here is a platform independent *gnuplot-only* solution.
How it's done:

- standard datafile separator is whitespace
- the function `getTime()` will check if the first string column is equal to `"Time"` and at the same time the second stringcolumn must be `'='` (because you have `Time` in the first column in the header as well). If this is true then column 3 is the time and you memorize this value in the variable `t0`.
- the function `getValue()` will check if the first string column is equal to `"Average"` and at the same time the 6th stringcolumn must be `"C_F[6]"`. If this is true then column 8 is the value and memorize this value in `y0`, sum it up in `ySum` and increase the counter `c` by 1. If it is false, the function's return value will be `NaN` and nothing will be plotted. Note, the function has to check the first column because in case there is no 6th column the check will fail.
- calculate the average by `yAvg=ySum/c` and plot and print it into the graph.

You might notice that the plotted datapoints in the first plot are not connected although the plotting style `with linespoints` was used. The reason is that there are empty lines in the input file and gnuplot will interrupt curves at empty lines.

Hence, in case you want connected lines you have to remove these empty lines which you can do by plotting the file each line as a whole (`set datafile separator "\n"`) into a datablock table (`with table`). This requires gnuplot>=5.2.0. Furthermore, by using `set datafile missing NaN` gnuplot will not interrupt lines at `NaN` values.

This extraction can easily be adapted to any other input data format.

**Data:** Save the OP's data example as `SO43427046.dat`

**Script:** (the first solution works with gnuplot>4.4.4, Nov. 2011 and the second solution with gnuplot>=5.2.0, Sept. 2017)

```
### extract specific data from a file
reset

FILE = "SO/SO43427046.dat"

getTime(col1,col2,col3)  = strcol(col1) eq "Time" && strcol(col2) eq "=" ? t0=column(col3) : t0
getValue(col1,col2,col3) = strcol(col1) eq "Average" && strcol(col2) eq "C_F[6]" ? \
                           (y0=column(col3),ySum=ySum+y0,c=c+1,y0) : NaN
set key top left
set ytics 0.02

set multiplot layout 2,1

    ySum = c  = 0
    t0   = y0 = NaN 
    plot FILE u (getTime(1,2,3)):(getValue(1,6,8)) \
         w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" ti "unconnected points", \
         (yAvg=ySum/c) w l lc rgb "blue" ti sprintf("Average: %g",yAvg)

    set table $Data
        set datafile separator "\n"
        plot FILE u (strcol(1)) w table
        set datafile separator whitespace
    unset table
    set datafile missing NaN
    ySum = c  = 0
    t0   = y0 = NaN 
    plot $Data u (getTime(1,2,3)):(getValue(1,6,8)) w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" ti "linespoints", \
         (yAvg=ySum/c) w l lc rgb "blue" ti sprintf("Average: %g",yAvg)

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]